# Date on x-axis in barplot in R

Tags: r, date, bar-chart

I'm very new to R. I have been trying to do this task for a while so far and I'm not succeeding. I need to produce barplot with dates on the x-axis(in the format month(numeric)-year). I have 36 data pieces.

```
2010 01    20  
2010 02    29 

2010 03    24    
2010 04    10

2010 05    14    
2010 06    19    
2010 07    25    
2010 08    30     
2010 09    36    
2010 10    34    
2010 11    34     
2010 12    25    
2011 01    27     
2011 02    48     
2011 03    79    
2011 04    76    
2011 05    58    
2011 06    56   
2011 07    65    
2011 08    66    
2011 09   120    
2011 10   126    
2011 11   139    
2011 12   109     
2012 01    94    
2012 02    48    
2012 03    87    
2012 04    86    
2012 05    97  
2012 06    92    
2012 07   100     
2012 08    95  
2012 09    94    
2012 10    77   
2012 11    88    
2012 12    57
```

The first column is a year the second one, month and the third one, number of sunspots in this month.

I need to produce bar plot with a number of sunspots on the y-axis and dates on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

We could `paste` the 'year' and 'month' column and create a 'yearmon' Class object with `as.yearmon` from `library(zoo)`.  Set the names of the third column of the dataset with 'YearMon' and plot with `barplot`.

```
library(zoo)
YearMon <- as.yearmon(with(df1, paste(year, month)), '%Y %m')
barplot(setNames(df1[,3], YearMon))
```

If you need the 'x axis' labels in the format `%m-%Y`, `format` the 'YearMon' and specify it in the `names.arg`.

```
barplot(df1[,3], names.arg=format(YearMon, '%m-%Y'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L), month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), number = c(20L, 
29L, 24L, 10L, 14L, 19L, 25L, 30L, 36L, 34L, 34L, 25L, 27L, 48L, 
79L, 76L, 58L, 56L, 65L, 66L, 120L, 126L, 139L, 109L, 94L, 48L, 
87L, 86L, 97L, 92L, 100L, 95L, 94L, 77L, 88L, 57L)), .Names = c("year", 
"month", "number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```